# Haskell Eclipse Linux and Buildwrapper

Tags: linux, eclipse, haskell

I am kind of new Eclipse user, and Haskell too. I keep trying  to understand what is wrong and what to do, as my Eclipse after I installed Haskell platform keeps me saying following

```
Configuring Test1-0.1...
buildwrapper: Left over temporary directory not removed: /tmp/dynamic-cabal.23
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package Cabal-1.22.0.0
```

I tried it on Ubuntu and Archlinux. Same behaviour. I have also read a lot of forums, and there is kind of information about GHC versions, cabal versions, and buildwrapper versions issues, but I could not figure how to fix that thing... 
For example like here https://github.com/JPMoresmau/BuildWrapper/issues/18
I tried cabal install cabal-install Eclipse started to behave a little different, cycling this over and over and over...

```
configuring because setup_config not present
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Test1-0.1...
```

Any help please...

Comment: "cannot satisfy -package Cabal-1.22.0.0" - do you have this version of Cabal?

Comment: yes.. I do have this locally, but globally I have 1.18. And I am really confused with this stuff.
ghc-pkg list
/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
Cabal-1.18.1.5

/home/mikhail/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.22.0.0

Comment: If you have two different versions of Cabal, you probably have two different versions of cabal-install. This may be a problem with using the wrong cabal-install. Make sure that the newest version is first on the path (the cabal-install which comes with the Haskell Platform is not overwritten when you do `cabal install cabal-install`).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it qualify for answer, I hope so.

The problem was that when I install GHC from standard ubuntu and arch repository, it installs **Cabal-1.18.1.5** and **Cabal-Install-1.22.0.0** system wide. And this causing EclipseFP plugin to install buidwrapper version which was supposed to work with 1.22 Cabal, while I actually had 1.18. Eclipse setting for Haskell said I had Cabal 1.22 (which was wrong).

What I did is added ArchHaskell repository, and installed everything from there, which got me 1.18 combo of Cabal and Cabal-install. EclipseFP worked it OK, finally.

I think there was a way to move local install up in hierarchy so EclipseFP would pick it up. But I understood it may be too late.